# more efficient way to get monthly counts in Python/Pyspark

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table DF look like below

```
ID   Days
1    30
2    55
3    32
4    12
5    100
.....
```

and I want to get a count as below:

```
month                           count
30 days and greater             20,000
60 days and greater             15,323
90 days and greater             11,232
.....
3600 days and greater           55
```

my code is really simple and straighforward, I just applied filter for each month, and get counts, then I copied and paste into Excel, such as below:

```
month1 = df.filter("Days >= 30").agg(countDistinct('ID')).show() 
month2 = df.filter("Days>= 60").agg(countDistinct('ID')).show() 
month3 = df.filter("Days >= 90").agg(countDistinct('ID')).show() ....
```

which is really not efficient.

I wonder if there is any easier way to do it? and create a table just like that.

Thanks at advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first divide the number of days by 30 and then group the values:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.shell import spark
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(ID=1, Days=30),
    Row(ID=2, Days=55),
    Row(ID=3, Days=32),
    Row(ID=4, Days=12),
    Row(ID=5, Days=100),
    Row(ID=6, Days=3600)
])

# Calculating quantity of months
df = df.withColumn('total_months', f.floor(f.col('Days') / f.lit(30)))

# Group and count distinct
df = df.groupBy('total_months').agg(f.countDistinct('ID').alias('count'))

# Adding description
df = df.withColumn('month', f.concat(f.col('total_months') * f.lit(30), f.lit(' days and greater')))

# Cumulative sum
window = Window.orderBy(f.col('total_months').desc()).rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
df = df.withColumn('count', f.sum('count').over(window))

# Selecting only required columns and sorting asc
(df
 .select('month', 'count')
 .sort('total_months')
 .show(truncate=False))
```

Output

```
+---------------------+-----+
|month                |count|
+---------------------+-----+
|0 days and greater   |6    |
|30 days and greater  |5    |
|90 days and greater  |2    |
|3600 days and greater|1    |
+---------------------+-----+
```

Comment: Hi, for your answer, if the days = 3600, it only get include in 3600 days and greater, but in my logic, it should get include from all month. so 3600 days ID should get count in 0 days and greater, 30 days and greater, 90 days and greater, and 3600 days and greater. not just in 3600 days and greater 1 category.

Comment: Hi Kafels, thanks for the update. it still not line up my logic. so for your example. we have 6 row. and for 0 days and greater, the count should be 6, since all 6 ID have days >= 0. for 30 days and greater, the count will be 5, since ID 1,2,3.5.6 all have days >= 30; and for 90 days and greater, the count will be 2, since only ID 5 and 6 have days >= 90. and for last one, 3600 days and greater, the count will be 1, since only ID 6 has days >=3600. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @yokielove updated, just changing window order

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can make an extra `month` column to capture the month of each ID depends on the days, the aggregate by that month to get the count for each month

```py
(df
    .withColumn('month', F
        .when(F.col('days') >= 90, 3)
        .when(F.col('days') >= 60, 2)
        .when(F.col('days') >= 30, 1)
        .otherwise(0)
    )
    .groupBy('month')
    .agg(F.countDistinct('ID').alias('count_distinct_id'))
    .show()
)

# +-----+-----------------+
# |month|count_distinct_id|
# +-----+-----------------+
# |    1|                3|
# |    3|                1|
# |    0|                1|
# +-----+-----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it only come back with month 1.

Comment: you can add more conditions above `.when(F.col('days') >= 90, 3)`, just remember the largest days go first, then smaller days follow.